# Set the scale in ColorFunction

Tags: plotting, color

The following plot (A)

```
 ListLinePlot[{0,1,2,3},ColorFunction->"TemperatureMap"]
```

goes from blue to read.

The following plot (B)

```
ListLinePlot[{4,5,6,7},ColorFunction->"TemperatureMap"]
```

goes also from blue to read.

I want the colors to be correlated to the number to be plotted, not the position in the list (as above). Therefore I would like (A) to go from white to yellow (approx.) and (B) from yellow to red (approx.).

How can I make the color to be correlated with the value of the number to be plotted and not the position in the list?

Comment: Yeah....this is no duplicate. It's related, but not nearly a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is due to the fact, that the default setting is `ColorFunctionScaling -> True`.
You'll have to set `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` with the downside, that you'll now have to take care of a proper scaling:

```
ListLinePlot[{0, 1, 2, 3}, ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap", #2/7] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

> [image: Plot1]

```
ListLinePlot[{4, 5, 6, 7}, ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap", #2/7] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

> [image: Plot2]

Comment: how could I fix the ColorFunction, such that I can see a blue->green colour gradient in a y axes range of 0.05 (f. ex. -0.04<y<0.01). I tried to play around with the number multiplying #2, but I did not succeed.

Comment: @Mencia `ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Blue, Green}, (#2 + 0.04)/0.05] &)` should give you the desired result.

Comment: Thanks great! Let say now, that I do ...Blend[{Blue,White,Green}... and that I want the center of the white span to be at y=0 always, i.e., to have a symmetric Colour Gradient around y=0 (White). How can I do this?

Comment: @Mencia `ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{-0.04, Blue}, {0, White}, {0.01, 
      Green}}, #2] &)`?

Comment: @Mencia Or `ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{-0.04, Blue}, {0, White}, {0.04, 
      Green}}, #2] &)` depending on what you mean with symmetric.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! You solved my problem!

Answer (score 3):

Your plots has `{1,2,3,4}` and `{1,2,3}` for the values of `x`, and, unless an explicit function is used as the `ColorFunction` the default argument is taken to be `x`. Hence the same color in both of your plots. If you want the color to change with `y` you need to use a function that specifies that dependence:

```
 ListLinePlot[{0, 1, 2, 3}, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
   PlotStyle -> Thickness[.02], 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][y]]]
   (* or ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap", #2] &) *)
```

[image]

```
 ListLinePlot[{4, 5, 6}, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
     PlotStyle -> Thickness[.02], 
     ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][y]]]
```

[image]

You can also use the same rescaled color function for both plots:

```
Row[ListLinePlot[#, PlotStyle -> Thickness[.02], PlotLabel -> #, 
     ImageSize -> 400, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
     ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 
     ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {-6, 6}}][y]]] & /@ 
  {{0, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]
```

[image]