# Color function for an integer valued 3D plot

Tags: plotting

I am plotting a function in 3D that takes integer values. I would like each integer height to appear as a different colour. There should be an easy way to do this but I am struggling with passing data to these colorfunctions. Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks!

So far this is what I have got to work:

```
Plot3D[
  p[1][a, b, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  {a, 0, Pi/2},
  {b, 0, Pi/2}, 
  PlotRange -> All,
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"
]
```

TemperatureMap does not change quickly enough for two adjacent integers. Is there a way to speed up its change? Or to define a new colorfunction that works as I describe?

An example of what I am thinking of is:

`Plot3D[Position[{Round[a + b], Round[a - b]}, 
   Min[{Round[a + b], Round[a - b]}]][[1]], {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}]`

where it would be nice to have a unique colour for each of the two values this function takes (z=1 and z=2).

Comment: Do you have the definition of `p`? Do the colors need to have any continuity? Or just more or less "random" colors for each integer? Also, possibly related: [(58951)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58951/set-the-scale-in-colorfunction).
And if the function takes integer values as you write, you might want to look at [`DiscretePlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot3D.html)

Comment: p[j_][\[Tau]_, \[Chi]_, \[CapitalDelta]_, a_, b_, H_] := 
 Position[Flatten[
    Table[F[i][\[Tau], \[Chi], \[CapitalDelta], a, b, H], {i, 1, 8}]],
    RankedMin[
    Flatten[Table[
      F[i][\[Tau], \[Chi], \[CapitalDelta], a, b, H], {i, 1, 8}]], 
    j]][[1]]  for tables F[1] to F[8].  

The colours don't need any continuity - I just want them to be as different as possible so that a bird's eye view of the plot will show a clear change in height.

Comment: Could you [format your definition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24793/how-do-i-use-formatting-in-comments) in such a way that it's usable? Also, `F[1]` to `F[8]` are missing... And did you look into using other plots to visualize the results (e.g. the suggested `DiscretePlot3D` or others)? `Plot3D` is really not designed for discrete data... If you really need to use `Plot3D`, you could do something like `ColorFunction->ColorData[16],ColorFunctionScaling->False` with any of the discrete color schemes

Comment: I input continuous variables and get out discrete values - is this not better to do with Plot3D than DiscretePlot3D? I'm not sure how to comment all of my code without it exceeding the allowed characters.

Comment: I assumed it also effectively takes integers (as you wrong "Tables `F[1]` to `F[8]` and "function in 3D that takes integer values")... You can always edit the question to put the code where it belongs - also it is always nice to provide a minimal example showing the problem, instead of the full code (i.e. try to make a simple function that is enough to demonstrate the issue)

Comment: @Mathe172, thank you very much. A working example would be:

`Plot3D[Position[{Round[a + b], Round[a - b]}, 
   Min[{Round[a + b], Round[a - b]}]][[1]], {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}]`

So this maps into two values, 1 and 2, and it would be great to have the surface plotted red for value 1 and blue for value 2, say.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
Plot3D[
 Position[{Round[a + b], Round[a - b]}, Min[{Round[a + b], Round[a - b]}]][[1]],
 {a, -1, 1},
 {b, -1, 1},
 MaxRecursion -> 6,
 MeshFunctions -> {Ceiling@#3 + 0.001 &, #3 + 0.001 &, #1 &, #2 &},
 MeshShading -> ({{{#, Directive[Darker@#, Specularity@.1] & /@ #}}} &@ColorData[16, "ColorList"]),
 Mesh -> ({#, #, 10, 10} &@Range@10),
 MeshStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Black], Directive[Thick, Black], Automatic, Automatic},
 Exclusions -> None
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For a more interesting function:

```
Plot3D[
 Floor[2 Sin[a^2 + 2 b^2] + 2],
 {a, -2, 2},
 {b, -2, 2},
 MaxRecursion -> 6,
 MeshFunctions -> {Ceiling@#3 + 0.001 &, #3 + 0.001 &, #1 &, #2 &},
 MeshShading -> ({{{Darker /@ #, #}}} &@ColorData[16, "ColorList"]),
 Mesh -> ({#, #, 10, 10} &@Range@10),
 MeshStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Black], Directive[Thick, Black], Automatic, Automatic},
 Exclusions -> None
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

An explanation of the different options:

- [`MaxRecursion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html): Ensures that the edges of the plateaus are nice and sharp - increase/decrease as necessary
- [`MeshFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html): We're using `Mesh` to achieve the discrete colors instead of the blending done by `ColorFunction`. The mesh specifications produce four meshes, one at the bottom of the "walls", the other at the top (the `+0.001` prevents the lines from missing at a few points due to rounding)
- [`MeshShading`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshShading.html): Specifies the color to use for the different regions. Here, we use one of the color lists (see [`ColorData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorData.html) for a more complete list) in normal form and with [`Darker`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Darker.html) to get the walls a bit different from the plateaus. The specification needs to be an array of depth 4 (as we have four meshes), where two meshes (x,y) shouldn't affect the color, hence the two single-element levels.
- [`Mesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html): Specifies the actual positions of the four meshes - for both z-meshes, we specify all integers (the range needs to be adjusted depending on the plot), for x,y we specify that 10 lines should be drawn.
- [`MeshStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshStyle.html): For the two z-meshes, we specify `Directive[Thick,Black]` to increase visibility, the other two (x,y) we leave alone
- [`Exclusions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exclusions.html): Needed to make sure the walls are plotted.

Comment: Thank you - that's very helpful. Is there any way to keep the mesh in the x-y directions or will that break this solution?

Comment: @plotter I've updated the answer with x/y meshes